# Empty images in wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress

sorry for my English. 
I have installed wordpress theme “Dynamix”. Dynamix uses plugin WPBakery Visual Composer. When I insert “Single Image” in post, then image have empty src. Example:

```
<a class="fancybox galleryimg blackwhite " style="width:200px" data-fancybox-group="gallerygdgrid_1" title="Controller" href="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/circle1.png">
<img class="gallery-img " width="200" height="200" alt="Controller" src="" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
</a>
```

When I insert image using wordpress embedded “insert media” window all works fine.
Where is the problem?
Thanks You!